# Let $a, b, c$ be real numbers such that $3b > a^2$. Then the function g : $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ given by $g(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$ is

Tags: functions

Let $a, b, c$ be real numbers such that $3b > a^2$. Then the function g : $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ given by $g(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$ is
(A) one-one and onto
(B) onto but not one-one
(C) one-one but not onto
(D) neither one-one nor onto

I don’t know where to start. Any idea?

*My attempt:-* 
$a\ge0$
$\implies b > 0$
$g'(x) = 3x^2 + 2ax + b$
$D = (2a)^2 - 4(3)(b) = 4a^2 - 12b$

$3b > a^2 \iff 12b>4a^2 \iff 4a^2-12b < 0$
$\implies D < 0$
**No real roots**

Similarly for $ a<0 \implies b > 0$
$g'(x) = 3x^2 - 2ax + b$
$D = (-2a)^2 - 4(3)(b) = 4a^2 - 12b < 0$
**No real roots**

In either case function is strictly increasing because coefficient of $x^3$ is positive.
$\implies g(x)$ is one-one

As $\lim_{x\to -\infty}g(x)\to-\infty$ and as $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x) \to \infty$ because $x^3$ is greater than $x^2$
$\implies g(x)$ is onto

So option A?

Comment: when we are stuck, sometimes, a possible way is to perhaps try a few $a$ and $b$ that satisfies the condition? after that, edit your post to include your attempt.

Comment: Every cubic is either one-to-one and onto or neither, depending on its critical points. Since the derivative is a quadratic, this follows from whether the derivative has no roots or two distinct roots. (I'm excluding the boundary case of the double root, but you can figure that one out.)

Comment: @SammyBlack Your first sentence is not correct. (The "onto" part - I'm not giving many details here, because the OP should figure this out by themselves.)

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Thank you so much I guess I figured out the answer. I am answering my own question so please do let me know if I am correct or not.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I edited my questions. Please let me know if I am correct.

Comment: Thank you for editing your post. Also, good attempt. :) There isn't a need to separate into two cases for the gradient part.

Answer (score 2):

$g$ is a polynomial, it is continuous. Check that $\lim_{x \to -\infty} g(x) = -\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)=\infty$, hence it must be onto.

Now, let's inspect the gradient.

$$g'(x)=3x^2+2ax+b$$ which is convex quadratic function.

Examining the discriminant: $(2a)^2-4(3b)=4(a^2-3b)<0$, hence we conclude that the gradient is always positive. It is an increasing function.

Hence, you are right, the answer is indeed $A$.